# write_formula gives error unless i copy and paste exactly the same formula

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a python script that writes excel file in the end with xlsxwriter. Everything works but a formula is giving error upon launching and if i copy and paste the exactly same formula it gives the results expected.
here is the line:

```
worksheet.write_formula('I2', '=SUMIF(B2:B{0};1;F2:F{0})'.format(len(df.index)+1))
```

edit: i try to export as xml and i saw that xlsxwriter writes ; as |. I mean the error giving formula from xlsxwriter is:

```
<Cell ss:Formula="of:=SUMIF([.B2:.B11]|1|[.F2:.F11])">
<Data ss:Type="String">Err:508</Data>
```

Copy and pasted working formula is:

```
<Cell ss:Formula="of:=SUMIF([.B2:.B11];1;[.F2:.F11])">
<Data ss:Type="Number">485</Data>
```

I don't know what's the issue here. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto the given link i believe you will find your answer: [XlsxWriter: Working with Formulas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html)

Specifically the Non US Excel functions and syntax says:

Excel stores formulas in the format of the US English version, regardless of the language or locale of the end-user's version of Excel. Therefore formulas must be written with the US style separator/range operator which is a comma (not semi-colon). A formula with multiple values should be written as follows:

```
worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=SUM(1, 2, 3)')   # OK 

worksheet.write_formula('A2', '=SUM(1; 2; 3)')   # Semi-colon. Error on load.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Just a note that the [Dealing with #NAME? errors](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html#dealing-with-name-errors) section of the docs give a step by step guide to debugging issues with formulas in XlsxWriter.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change LibreOffice Settings > LibreOffice Calc > Formula to re-calculate on file load to always. But replacing ; as | is still exists

> LibreOffice intentionally does not recalculate older spreadsheets,
>   because as formulas are updated from version to version or between
>   different spreadsheet programs, the results can be different. Go to
>   Tools – Options – LibreOffice Calc, under 'Recalculation on file
>   load', change the two drop-downs, 'Excel 2007 and newer' and 'ODF
>   Spreadsheet (not saved by LibreOffice)', to 'Always recalculate'.
>   Click Ok, close the spreadsheet and LibreOffice. Now open the file in
>   LibreOffice and you should see that the formulas have recalculated.
>
> Also go to Tools – Cell Contents and be sure that AutoCalculate is
>   selected.